# How can I make this dropdown search bar look nicer?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Made a dropdown button and when clicked reveals a search bar, but it's not very good looking at all, what class can I use to make it fit in better? This is how it currently looks :

[image: My not nice looking search bar]

```
  <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Search<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <form>
          <div class="input-prepend">
          <div class="btn-group"><
          <button class="btn" tabindex="-1">Search</button>
          <select class="btn dropdown-toggle" style="width: 140px;">
          <option>Suncor</option>
          <option>Syncrude</option>
          <option>Albian Sands</option>
          </select>
          </div>
          <input type="text">
          </div>
          </form>
          </ul>
          </li>
          </ul>
```

Comment: can you setup a test page or a jsfiddle ?

Comment: @Shail not really, I have so many separate files included through php it would take a while :/ sorry. Also I'm not ready to release it to the public yet :)

Comment: Maybe just change it around a bit to make it look better: http://jsfiddle.net/huHJ8/ some padding on the drop-down would help too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this boostrap plugin to turn the `select` in a bootstrap `dropdown`.
https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select

Answer (score 0):

Not leveraging an existing bootstrap class here, but just adding a minor customization. This is at least one route you can use to tackle your problem. Note how the `.dropForm` class was added to the `<form>`.

http://jsfiddle.net/fhVnJ/3/

**CSS**

```
.w140 {
    width: 135px;    
}

.dropForm {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 12px 10px 12px;    
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Search<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <form class="dropForm">
                      <div class="input-prepend">
                          <div class="btn-group">
                              <button class="btn" tabindex="-1">Search</button>
                              <select class="w140">
                                  <option>Suncor</option>
                                  <option>Syncrude</option>
                                  <option>Albian Sands</option>
                              </select>
                          </div>
                          <input type="text" />
                      </div>
                  </form>
              </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

P.S. - Whatever you do, you will need to clean up your html markup where you have `<div class="btn-group"><`: the open angle bracket should be deleted.